# How to put/have value/data in options value=""?

Tags: javascript, html

can somebody help me how to put data in options value=""? Please see below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Preventive Maintenance Cost</h3>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">-- Select a model --</option> 
  <option value="accord_mm">Accord (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="accord_pro">Accord (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="brio_mm">Brio/Amaze (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="brio_pro">Brio/Amaze (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="city_mm">City (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="city_pro">City (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="civic_mm">Civic (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="civic_pro">Civic (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="crv_mm">CR-V (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="crv-pro">CR-V (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="crz_mm">CR-Z (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="crz_pro">CR-Z (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="hrv_mm">HR-V (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="hrv_pro">HR-V (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="jazz_mm">Jazz (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="jazz_pro">Jazz (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="legend_mm">Legend (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="legend_pro">Legend (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="mobilio_mm">Mobilio (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="mobilio_pro">Mobilio (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="odyssey_mm">Odyssey (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="odyssey_pro">Odyssey (Provincial)</option>
  <option value="pilot_mm">Pilot (Metro Manila)</option>
  <option value="pilot_pro">Pilot (Provincial)</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Details: </br>" + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I wanted to display the output as table with image according to the selected car model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Above code is working fine. You wanted to display a table according to the selected car model? I understand that, but what is your question?

Comment: @KapilaPerera, I'm trying to ask how can I display a data/image when you select a certain car model.

Comment: It depends on the way you want to show. Are those images in a folder. or you can keep those images in data-car-image or image url in data tag.

Comment: Images in image url in data tag. @KapilaPerera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you can store image path in the data tag or the image as image64 bit string

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">-- Select a model --</option> 
  <option data-image="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA1IAAAEsCAYAAADJkYKfAAAg" value="accord_mm">Accord (Metro Manila)</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">-- Select a model --</option> 
  <option data-image="{image-path} /src/images/accord_mm.jpg" value="accord_mm">Accord (Metro Manila)</option>
</select>
```

you can access the data value as `$('#mySelect').data("image")`

```
<img id="demo" src="">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var image-path= select.getAttribute('data-image');
    var image = document.getElementById("demo");
    image.src = image-path;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But how about, if I wanted to use images from the web?

Comment: replace the {image-path} with url of the web image

Comment: I see. But how can I display the image?

Comment: Does it look like this?
'<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">-- Select a model --</option> 
  <option data-image=
  {http://o.aolcdn.com/dims-global/dims3/GLOB/legacy_thumbnail/788x525/quality/85/http://o.aolcdn.com/commerce/autodata/images/CAC40HOC011A121001.jpg} value="accord_mm">
   Accord (Metro Manila)</option>'

Answer (score 1):

**how to put data in options value=""**

You dont need to put *data* in value, instead you can use `data` attribute.

Below is an example of how to use `data` attribute with `option`
For getting the image , i am using a tag called data-img. You can rename it , but it will be always like  `data-myChoiceOne,data-myChoiceTwo`.It need to have `data` in it. If you wan to pass the path of the image location , you can pass in the data attribute

**HTML**

```
<option value="">-- Select a model --</option>
<option value="accord_mm" data-img='http://img.autobytel.com/car-reviews/autobytel/11694-good-looking-sports-cars/2016-Ford-Mustang-GT-burnout-red-tire-smoke.jpg'>Accord (Metro Manila)</option>
<option value="accord_pro" data-img="http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/582de470e02ba72e008b4e76-1200/lamborghini-huracan-rwd-spyder.jpg">Accord (Provincial)</option>
```

**JS**

Create function which will be triggered on change in select, pass the `this` object in the function. Using this object you can get all the parameters of the selected option

```
function myFunction(obj) {
  //get image
  var img = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-img');
  //get the text
  var val = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
  //table where news rows will be appeneded
  var tab = document.getElementById("demo");
  //append new rows
  tab.appendChild(createTable(val, img))
}
```

// function accepting the text and image

```
function createTable(text, img) {
 //Creating new row
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  //creating cell for text
  var cellText = document.createElement('td');
  cellText.innerHTML = text;
  //creating cell for image
  var cellImg = document.createElement('td');
   // adding the image as style
  cellImg.style = "background-image:url(" + img + ");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:250px 180px;   width: 250px; height: 180px;"
  row.appendChild(cellText); // appending text cell
  row.appendChild(cellImg); // appending image cell 
  return row; // return the row

}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2xgtwfbn/4/)

Comment: Why does the image/s are not displayed? Only the "accord_mm" is displayed.

Comment: @LyraOpena can you please recheck the link

Answer (score 1):

(just correct)
Please, if you give a Question, you must give enough information. anyone just show you clue and not write code for you.

you want to show display picture but do not tell everyone about you picture.

(answare)
to show a image, web have many method to show the image. i just give you example :

```js
$("#car").change(function(){
  var directory = "../../../";  // example place of picture
  var picture = this.value;     // this a value if you change
  var format = ".png";          // this format you picture
  $("#display_car").attr({
    "src":directory+picture+format,
    "alt":"image "+picture+" is broken"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='car'>
  <option hidden selected>Pick Your Car</option>
  <option value='car1'>car1</option>
  <option value='car2'>car2</option>
</select>
<img id='display_car' />
<p>
Why broken? because in <img>, IF picture can't load, the alt is return :)
</p>
```